# Ext JS -DOM Query question

Tags: javascript, extjs

Ok another DOMQuery question. i think the EXT API docs are a little scarce on this.

Inside my FormPanel I have mulitple fieldsets, but need to find the one that has a header title of 'Test Results'.

Does anyone know if Ext provides a helper function to do something like this or will i need to do soemthing like `formPanel.findByType("fieldset", true)`, and then do a for each loop looking for that particular title...?

Thanks!

Comment: If you know which fieldset you need based on the title, why not just give it an id and use Ext.getCmp('my-fieldset')?  BTW, if you are looking at the DomQuery docs, that explains why they are "scarce" -- this question has nothing to do with DomQuery ;)

Comment: Though my response below does answer your question as stated I concur with bmoeskau that referencing the FieldSet directly by ID is likely a more elegant way of arriving at your goal.

Comment: thanks, yea , this applicatio i am working in is a 'data-drive' EXT site, and we don't currently support giving Fieldset's unique id's. we just let EXT create on the fly. which is why i dont know the id. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Ext.form.FormPanel's find method:

```
var fieldSets = formPanel.find('title', 'Test Results');
```

Be aware that the return value is an array of found items.

A slightly more paranoid way using Ext.util.MixedCollection's find method:

```
var fieldSet = formPanel.items.find(function( item ) {
    return item instanceof Ext.form.FieldSet
        && item.title == 'Test Results';
});
```

Here the return value is only the first item found.